# multiple dialog processes to controls? winapi / C++

Tags: c++, winapi, win32-process

I've just created multiple edit boxes (11x11 controls) based on this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Well, not exactly same, but I used the code in case WM_CREATE:  block to create huge number of controls.

I use this dialog process on the parent window:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK StartupDialogProc(HWND dialog, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg){
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        Init_Startup(dialog);
        return 1;
/*
    case EN_CHANGE:
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: 
          {
              HDC hdC = (HDC)wParam;

                COLORREF crColorBackground = RGB(255,0,0);  
                    if (crColorBackground)
                        SetBkColor(hdC, crColorBackground);

              SetTextColor( hdC, RGB(12,112,212) );

              SetBkMode( hdC, TRANSPARENT );

                RECT rect;
                GetClientRect( (HWND)lParam, &rect );                    
                HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(209,209,209) );
                   //FrameRect( hdC, &rect, hBrush );
                   Rectangle( hdC, (int)rect.left, (int)rect.top, (int)rect.right, (int)rect.bottom );
                DeleteObject( hBrush );

              LOGBRUSH lb;
              lb.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
              lb.lbColor = RGB(249,249,249);
              lb.lbHatch = 0;
              CreateBrushIndirect(&lb); // LRESULT
              // GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
              return 1;
          }
     break;
     */
    case WM_DESTROY:
      setts.options.page = GetDlgItemInt(dialog, IDC_O_STARTUP_PAGE, NULL, FALSE);
      setts.options.recent = GetDlgItemInt(dialog, IDC_O_STARTUP_RECENT, NULL, FALSE);
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(dialog, FALSE);    
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (wParam == IDOK) {
            EndDialog(dialog, TRUE);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is few things unclear to me:
1) if I would like to change color of border for all edit controls from id 5001 to id 5121, how to do that? To me, the commented code does not work (when would it be uncommented). It looks like I have this in incorrect place.
2) how correctly create the dialog processes to all the controls? Because there is big number and could be yet few times higher, should I just call a loop from 5001 to id 5121 and call the function:
INT_PTR CALLBACK EditDlgProc(HWND dialog, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) - that won't work, because every function would need to have different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the border color of edit control, you have to subclass the edit control and override `WM_NCPAINT`. That's a little advanced, and you don't really need it. You can just use `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` flag:

`CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT" ...`

Also make sure project manifest is setup so you get modern window's look.

This would be an error if it had not been commented out:

```
case EN_CHANGE:
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
```

Each case should end in `break;` or `return 0;`

Moreover, `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` should return a brush which was created on heap. It should not return 1. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

There are also other errors in that section, you should just get rid of that. See this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for painting.

Comment: Fallthrough between cases is perfectly legal, which is what trips up programmers.  Or by "error" do you mean a logic bug and not a compile error?

Comment: The only thing fundamentally wrong with the `case` statements is that `EN_CHANGE` is a sub-code of the `WM_COMMAND` message and not a message in its own right.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I wasn't clear about that. It's not a compile error, and it shouldn't be there at all as Jonathan pointed out.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Ahh, good rule of thumb.  For the richtext edit control is is `WM_NOTIFY`, for the plain `EDIT`, it is `WM_COMMAND`.

Comment: @Barmak: thanks. WS_EX_STATICEDGE better suits my needs. It's nice and cool tiny border, not black as the WS_BORDER style. WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE is inner edge border which does not look good to me when my editbox is very small, it also limited the count of characters -1(?).